# ¿Cómo crear una matriz 6x7 python?

Tags: python

Quiero saber como hacer una matriz en pycharm con python, una opinión estaría bien, pero si pueden dejar código se lo agradezco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo básico:

```
n = int(raw_input('Ingrese filas: '))  //tomar un valor para la cantidad de filas
m = int(raw_input('Ingrese columnas: ')) //tomar un valor para la cantidad de columnas
matriz = []
for i in range(n):
    raw = [] //nueva fila
    for j in range(m):
        raw.append(j) //nueva columna
    matriz.append(raw)
print 'Matriz M = ',matriz
```

Comment: Mario L como nombras raw_input? Me dice que lo he de nombrar

Comment: Ahí edité mi respuesta, esa línea estaba de más, perdón. Saludos!